# vb.net - bypass convert dialog / security warnings

Tags: vb.net

Is there anyway to disable the vb.net (2008) express popup for converting older projects as well as the security warning to browse the project? I'm fairly new to vb.net so of course I download lots of examples to learn off of and it is BEYOND annoying to have to convert every demo and then click ok to browse the code.

Is there no way to set defaults for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible, but I don't recommend it anyway. The conversion process is there to make sure that your code works as expected in newer versions.

VB does a lot behind the scenes to make the project work. Stuff we never see unless we go looking for it. These things can change between versions (namespaces and classes get added or removed, renamed or restructured), and if you don't convert, you could find yourself with an application that does nothing useful...